# Retrieve the ID of an uploaded document

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I use the code below to upload a file to SharePoint Online using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

When the file has been uploaded a new record in the library has been created - how can I get the ID of that record? I want to reload that record to read a calculated field in SharePoint (calculated after uploading).

```
    FI = New IO.FileInfo(filename)

    Dim fileInformation As FileCreationInformation
    Dim item As ListItem
    Dim library As List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(docLibrary)

    ctx.Load(library, Function(x) x.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    fileInformation = New FileCreationInformation
    With fileInformation
        .Url = library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl & "/" & Filename
        .Overwrite = True
        .Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFilename)
    End With

    Dim fs As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(newFilename, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim flciNewFile As FileCreationInformation = New FileCreationInformation()
    flciNewFile.ContentStream = fs
    flciNewFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(newFilename)
    flciNewFile.Overwrite = True

    Dim docs As List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(docLibrary)
    Dim uploadFile As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile)

    item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields
    item("ColumnA") = "some metadata"
    item("ColumnB") = "some metadata"
    item.Update()

    ctx.Load(uploadFile)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
ctx.Load(uploadFile, Function(f) f.ListItemAllFields)
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
MsgBox(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Id)
```

Comment: Glad to hear you have resolved the issue, you can accept your own post as answer so that it could help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is the id of new uploaded file item:

uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Id

Updated:

Please Load the uploadFile.ListItemAllField in ClientContext like below:

```
item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields
ctx.Load(item)
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

[ListItem.Id property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee539237%28v%3Doffice.15%29)

Comment: Hm, in which codeline do I use it? I always receive: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException: 'The property or field 'Id' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.'

Comment: @StefanMeyer, Updated the answer, please check it.  Will need to Load in ClientContext.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working. I solved it now by this:ctx.Load(uploadFile, Function(f) f.ListItemAllFields)
        ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        MsgBox(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Id)

Comment: @StefanMeyer, yes, this is the same as I posted, just Load it in ClientContext. Remeber, not only the Id of uploadedItem. If you want to access other object, make sure it have been loaded in ClientContext :)